# How to save scrollback text to a file for a linux console using framebuffer

Tags: linux, terminal

I've used the `fbcon=scrollback:128k` boot option to get a bigger scrollback, I can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to see the scrollbacked text, how can I save this scrolled back text to a file so I can view it in an editor?

I've googled and found a resource that lists [many screenshot programs for Linux](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Apps/screen-capture.html), but it looks like none of these tools meet my requirement.

Comment: Isn't the output uou want saved to `/var/log/dmesg`?

Comment: There seems to be an explanation & possibly [useful answers to your question on SE Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690703/save-current-terminal-scrollback-to-file)

Answer (score -1):

You can mark all text with the mouse, change to the editor, and hit the middle mouse button (scroll wheel) to paste the text.

Comment: This is not easy to do for me because I want to save text more than one screen.

Comment: Since you can mark more than one screen, you can copy+paste more than one screen. It isn't the most comfortable operation, I admit.